# strcmp error 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble by compiling this code in Release mode (it's working perfectly in Debug mode)

```
#include "MemoryManagement.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Colors.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
using namespace std;

MemoryManagement::MemoryManagement()
{
    handle = NULL;
}

MemoryManagement::~MemoryManagement()
{
    CloseHandle(handle);
}

DWORD MemoryManagement::getProcess(const char* proc)
{
    HANDLE hProcessId = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    DWORD process = 0;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);

    SetConsoleColor(colors::blue_bright);
    cout << "Searching game..." << endl;

    while (!process)
    {
        do {
            if (!strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, proc))
            {
                process = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
                CloseHandle(hProcessId);
                handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, process);
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hProcessId, &pEntry));
    }

    SetConsoleColor(colors::green_bright);
    cout << "Game found!" << endl << endl;

    return process;
}

uintptr_t MemoryManagement::getModule(DWORD procId, const char* modName)
{
    HANDLE hModule = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;
    mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(mEntry);

    do
    {
        if (!strcmp(mEntry.szModule, modName))
        {
            CloseHandle(hModule);
            return (DWORD)mEntry.hModule;
        }
    } while (Module32Next(hModule, &mEntry));
    return 0;
}

DWORD MemoryManagement::getAddress(DWORD addr, std::vector<DWORD> vect)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += vect[i];
    }
    return addr;
}
```

The error output is this one:

```
1>c:\users\kuhi\source\repos\cs\cs\memorymanagement.cpp(31): error C2664: 'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'
1>c:\users\kuhi\source\repos\cs\cs\memorymanagement.cpp(31): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\kuhi\source\repos\cs\cs\memorymanagement.cpp(54): error C2664: 'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [256]' to 'const char *'
1>c:\users\kuhi\source\repos\cs\cs\memorymanagement.cpp(54): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Done building project "CS.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I see the problem is with strcmp, that I'm giving a wrong data type...

I searched around and didn't find a fix that match my situation...

Why it's working in Debug mode but not in Release mode?

I have to compare 2 strings that can change every time I open the program, so I don't get how to give the arguments as const

Comment: What's not clear about "cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'" ?

Comment: it's not clear how I can deal with it, if I knew I was not asking this question, and why it's working in debug mode and not in release

Comment: You deal with it by fixing your code so that the first parameter is a `const char *`, or something that can be implicitly converted to it. How you fix your code is entirely up to you, but this is the reason for the compilation error.

Comment: Yes I can read the error output, I already said the error is with the data type, but that's not answering my question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, that would be the wrong fix. The correct approach is to use the right function for the job, not to mangle your data inputs to hack around type mismatches. Please _stop_ putting answers in the comments section where they cannot be downvoted when wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make sense for this to work in debug mode; that must be a mis-observation.

`WCHAR` is a Microsoft alias for `wchar_t` (or `unsigned short` if needs be) ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar)).

You have an array of these things.

Said array will never be compatible with `const char*`, because `wchar_t` and `char` are two different things. So, you cannot pass your array to functions that require `const char*`, like `strcmp`.

C (and, by extension, C++) also provides a wide-character version of `strcmp` that you can use: [`wcscmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscmp).

Comment: thank you very much that's what I was looking for

Comment: `wcscmp` is standard C.

Comment: @PeteBecker So it is! Thanks